# Create array of pointers from an array of double in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, unmanaged

I'm trying to create an array of pointer references to a double array.  For example;

```
double[] mylist = new double[100];
fixed (double* p = mylist) { }
```

Now as the MSDN documentation states, that is equivalent to p = &mylist[0]  This is only taking the first value, is it possible to create an array of pointers to variables in another array?  Or is the practice to use only one pointer?

Thanks for any help, in advance

Comment: int vs double - can you clarify if that is just a typo? Also.... what is the question/problem?

Comment: Okay, I've attempted to clarify.

Comment: `p = &mylist[0]` - This is pointing to the first element of the array. When you have the pointer to the first element, then there shouldn't be any problem to get to the rest of the array elements. What are you trying to achieve here, are you doing P/Invoke stuff?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to call a DLLimport and pass a array pointer reference, and stating it's size as a parameter.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array elements are located in contiguous memory, so it's usually suffcient to have a pointer to the first element and do pointer arithmetic to get to the others.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a typed pointer to a vector (or, more accurately, the first item *in* a vector), it works like in C/C++; all you need is the single pointer, and you can use it *either* as an individual item *or* as a zero-based array; you can still access `p[3]`, except now *instead* of using array access metaphors, this is applying "3 * the-item-size as an offset relative to `p`". So:

```
p[3] = 1.0;
```

is fine. Note, of course, that if you go *outside* the array bounds accidentally, bad things will happen.